# Should I use Multithreading or Async IO to speed up a network bound task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a python function that SSHs into a device, runs some commands and uses the data to make HTTP calls. I want to make `migrate_devices` run in parallel when processing the devices.

Existing function, simplified:

```py
def migrate_devices(devices: List[str]):
    for ip in devices: # each loop can be run in parallel without any race conditions 
        data = collect_data_via_ssh(ip) # SSHing in takes some time
        new_data = process_data(data) # massages the data
        make_http_calls(data) # takes some time
```

The devices can be SSHed independently of each other. The HTTP calls for each device are independent, and don't depend on data from other devices.

The biggest chunk of time is spent on waiting for the device to respond to SSH commands and waiting for the HTTP response. So essentially, I want to run each loop in parallel. Is multithreading the way to go or is async/await a better fit?
I can use python 3.10+ if needed and use 3.12 if there's useful syntax additions

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|            migrate_devices(devices: List[str])           |                      
|             +---------------------------+                |
|             |  for device in devices:   |                |
|             +----+--------------------+-+                |
|                  |                    |                  |
|           +------v-----------+   +----v--------------+   |
|           | ssh into device 1|   | SSH into device 2 |   |
|           | Make API calls   |   | Make API calls    |   |
|           +------------------+   +-------------------+   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm familiar with Javascript's async mechanism and I wanted to implement something similar:

```py
async def process_single_device(ip):
    data = await collect_data_via_ssh(ip)
    new_data = process_data(data) # massages the data
    await make_http_calls(data)
    return success_or_failure_message

async def migrate_devices(devices: List[str]):
    all_tasks = []
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for device in devices:
            device_task = tg.create_task(process_single_device(ip=device))
            all_tasks.append(device_task)
    # all tasks would complete at this point
    for device in all_tasks:
        print(f"Device result: {device.result()}")
```

Should I continue with this approach or switch to threads?

Is this what python is doing when I use async/await?

```
                                   +
                                   |
         ---------+                |         +--------+
         |device 1|                |         |device 2|
         ---------+                |         +--------+
                                   |
          SSH into device 1+       |
                           | while waiting
                           +-for SSH,------> ssh into device 2
                             process next device +
                                   |             |
                                   |             |
                                   |             |
                                   |             |
make HTTP call+ for device 1<--------------------+ while waiting for device 2 SSH,
              |                    |               make HTTP calls for device 1
              |
              |                    |
              +----------------------------> make HTTP calls for device 2
                                   |
                                   |
                                   +
```

Comment: For your case - if you can make `collect_data...`, `process_data`, `make_http_calls` asychronous, you use any of them or even both, as it will not differ in result (assuming there is not that big amount of devices, in which case stick to the mixing them or use threading only). If not just use threading.

Comment: Briefly, if your functions wait for some response most of the time (and you can make them `await` it instead of blocking the thread), then it's better to use async

Comment: @sudden_appearance this was my thought as well. Even a single threaded async function will give me performance benefits over my current sequential approach. I might just skip the complexity of multithreading altogether or implement it only if I have perf issues

Comment: actually - it is the other way around: sometimes changing the code fo concurrency using multi-threading will be easier than re-writing it to use asyncio: multi-threading won't require rewritting your code, and thinking of a way of making asynchronous I/O on the lowest level (will involve using an async ssh client if the library you are using do not support it). Sometimes, adding concurrency with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is a matter of less than 10 LoC.

Comment: I see, i didn’t consider that factor. I’ll evaluate using thread pool executors instead